# Erro ao usar scanf("%[^\n]") em sequência

Tags: c, string, struct, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct person{
    char name[100];  
    char address[100];
    int age;
} Person;

int main()
{
    Person pessoa;

    printf("Digite seu nome:\n");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", pessoa.name);

    printf("Digite seu endereço:\n");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", pessoa.address);

    printf("Digite sua idade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &pessoa.age);

    printf("Nome: %s\nEndereço: %s\nIdade: %d\n", pessoa.name, pessoa.address, pessoa.age);

    return 0;
}
```

Gostaria de saber porque apos utilizar o `scanf("%99[^\n]", pessoa.name);` o segundo

`scanf("%99[^\n]", pessoa.address);` está sendo pulando automaticamente

Comment: José, já tentou efetuar o scanf com %s?

Comment: Sim, mas estava causando o mesmo erro, até com apenas um scanf no código

Comment: Pelo que pude entender, no link que você forneceu, quando dou um enter o buffer de entrega não consome o \n correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque nas primeiras duas chamadas do `scanf()` você pede para ler **exclusivamente** characteres que não são quebra de linha. Isso implica no `scanf()` deixar o caractere de quebra de linha no *buffer* do `stdin` até que uma chamada consuma o caractere de quebra, ou seja, até a terceira chamada (`scanf("%d")`).

O que você pode fazer para resolver é "espiar" o próximo caractere que está no *buffer* logo após cada uma das duas primeiras chamadas do `scanf()` e consumi-lo caso seja uma quebra de linha. Exemplo:

```c
int main()
{
    Person pessoa = { "", "", -1 };
    char c;

    printf("Digite seu nome:\n");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", pessoa.name);

    /* Retira o primeiro (ou próximo) caractere que está no buffer
     * do stdin e devolve (para o mesmo buffer) caso não seja uma
     * quebra de linha. */
    c = getc(stdin); 
    if (c != '\n')
        ungetc(c, stdin);

    printf("Digite seu endereço:\n");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", pessoa.address);

    /* "Espia" novamente o buffer do stdin para consumir a quebra
     * de linha. Essa segunda chamada não é obrigatória porque o
     * próximo scanf() será com a format string %d, mas deixei aqui
     * para manter o padrão de sempre consumir um newline após as
     * chamadas scanf("%[^\n]"). */
    c = getc(stdin);
    if (c != '\n')
        ungetc(c, stdin);

    printf("Digite sua idade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &pessoa.age);

    printf("Nome: %s\nEndereço: %s\nIdade: %d\n", pessoa.name, pessoa.address, pessoa.age);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fernando você poderia me informa o que esse trecho ``` c = getc(stdin);
    if (c != '\n')
        ungetc(c, stdin); ``` está fazendo por debaixo do capo.

Comment: @JoséIsaac adicionei comentários em cima dos trechos de código. Verifique se são suficientes para entender. Caso não seja me avise que posso melhorar a explicação

Comment: muito obrigado, consegui entender perfeitamente, vlw.

Answer (score 3):

Estão dando soluções complicadas demais...

Como fazer:

```
Person pessoa;

printf("Digite seu nome:\n");
scanf(" %99[^\n]", pessoa.name); // um espaco antes de %99[^\n]

printf("Digite seu endereço:\n");
scanf(" %99[^\n]", pessoa.address);  // um espaco antes de %99[^\n]

printf("Digite sua idade:\n");
scanf("%d", &pessoa.age); // aqui nao precisa do espaco antes do %d
```

Pronto!

Explicação: num scanf um espaço em branco consome **todos** os espaços em branco (' '), tabs ('\x9'), avanco de linha ('\n') e retorno de cursor ('\r') que estiverem em sequência.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo usar alguma dessas funções:

```
void limpa_linha() {
    scanf("%*[^\n]"); /* Lê todos os caracteres "indesejados" e descarta os mesmos, exceto o '\n' */
    scanf("%*c"); /* Lê o caractere '\n' e descarta o mesmo, limpando assim o stdin */ 
}
```

Ou essa:

```
void fflush_stdin() {
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); /* getchar() em loop */
}
```

Uso de uma delas:

```
Person pessoa;

printf("Digite seu nome:\n");
scanf(" %99[^\n]", pessoa.name); /* um espaco antes de %99[^\n] para descartar os eventuais espaços em branco antes da string ser digitada */
limpa_linha();

printf("Digite seu endereço:\n");
scanf(" %99[^\n]", pessoa.address); 
limpa_linha();

printf("Digite sua idade:\n");
scanf("%d", &pessoa.age); 
limpa_linha();
```